# Liip imagine cant create thumb - with larget than 2MB

Tags: php, resize, image-resizing, liipimaginebundle, php-imagine

So, basically.. I can upload files larger than 2MB (php.ini changed in three different locations - lol..).

- PHP: 5.6
- Symfony Liip Imagine (probably GD driver, dunno how to check
  it?)
- memory_limit = 128MB (tryd change to 512MB)
- upload_max_filesize = 30M
- post_max_size = 30M

and still... if file have 2.1M thumb failed - under than everythink works fine. Thumb just going to location /resolved/cache/ and that means fail as I know ;)

**any Ideas where or what I should looking for?**